# Detecting dual monitors in Silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight, html

Is there a way to detect if the user has 1 monitor or 2? And if so, is it possible to determine which is left and which is right and open a browser window on that specific monitor?

I'm looking for either a Silverlight solution to this problem or a Javascript / DOM solution or an HTML5 solution.

This is an in-browser app, by the way

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript, Silverlight and Flash are bounded by the sandbox within the browser where they are running. To do what you require, would most likely mean breaking out of that sandbox which would be a huge security concern and is not allowed.

Comment: Would it be possible to do this out-of-browser? Like a silverlight oob application?

Comment: http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Determine-screen-resolution-in-Silverlight-OOB.aspx